# Radix Sort for floats in C - negative values get corrupted

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, negative-number, radix-sort

I'm translating [Michael Herf's radix sort](http://stereopsis.com/radix.html) into straight C code. For positive values it works just fine, but the negative values are getting corrupted, as seen here:

```
Input:
-0.100000 0.100000 0.000000 0.700000 0.900000 -0.400000 -1.000000 0.200000 -0.400000 -0.700000 
Expected output:
-1.000000 -0.700000 -0.400000 -0.400000 -0.100000 0.000000 0.100000 0.200000 0.700000 0.900000
Actual output:
-44.799999 -11.200000 -11.200000 -6.400000 -4.000000 0.000000 0.100000 0.200000 0.700000 0.900000
```

How to fix this?

Code (on Eclipse CDT, Ubuntu 16.10, compiled with  GCC 6.2):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>  // for prefetch

#define PFVAL   64
#define PFVAL2  128
#define PF(x, i)    _mm_prefetch((char *)((x)+(i)+PFVAL), 0)
#define PF2(x, i)   _mm_prefetch((char *)((x)+(i)+PFVAL2), 0)

#define HISTOGRAM   2048
#define HISTOGRAMS  6144    // 3*histogram

#define FLIP_FLOAT_A(x) ((x)^(((x) >> 31) | 0x80000000))
#define FLIP_FLOAT_B(x) ((x)^((((x) >> 31)-1) | 0x80000000))

// utils for accessing 11-bit quantities
#define _0(x)   (x & 0x7FF)
#define _1(x)   (x >> 11 & 0x7FF)
#define _2(x)   (x >> 22 )

void radixsort_float(float *a, size_t num) {
    uint32_t *base = (uint32_t *)a;
    size_t arraysize = num*sizeof(uint32_t);
    uint32_t *aux = malloc(arraysize);

    uint32_t byte0[HISTOGRAMS] = { 0 };
    uint32_t *byte1 = byte0+HISTOGRAM;
    uint32_t *byte2 = byte1+HISTOGRAM;

    // 1. parallel histogramming pass
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        PF(base, i);

        uint32_t bi = FLIP_FLOAT_A(base[i]);

        ++byte0[_0(bi)];
        ++byte1[_1(bi)];
        ++byte2[_2(bi)];
    }

    // 2. sum the histograms: each histogram entry
    // records the number of values preceding itself
    uint32_t sum0 = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    uint32_t total;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < HISTOGRAM; i++) {
        total = byte0[i]+sum0;
        byte0[i] = sum0-1;
        sum0 = total;

        total = byte1[i]+sum1;
        byte1[i] = sum1-1;
        sum1 = total;

        total = byte2[i]+sum2;
        byte2[i] = sum2-1;
        sum2 = total;
    }

    // byte 0: floatflip entire value, read/write histogram, write out flipped
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        uint32_t bi = FLIP_FLOAT_A(base[i]);
        uint32_t pos = _0(bi);

        PF2(base, i);
        aux[++byte0[pos]] = bi;
    }

    // byte 1: read/write histogram, copy
    // aux -> array
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        uint32_t ai = aux[i];
        uint32_t pos = _1(ai);
        PF2(aux, i);
        base[++byte1[pos]] = ai;
    }

    // byte 2: read/write histogram, copy & flip out
    // base -> aux
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num; ++i) { 
        uint32_t bi = base[i];
        uint32_t pos = _2(bi);

        PF2(base, i);
        aux[++byte2[pos]] = FLIP_FLOAT_B(bi);
    }

    memcpy(base, aux, arraysize);
    free(aux);
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, what is corrupted isn't obvious, as you don't show what the expected result is.  Your example code is large.  Can you trim it down a bit?

Comment: Added expected output for clarification. But trimming isn't really possible, I only shaved off a few empty lines, kept the rest for readability purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your FLIP_FLOAT_A macro -- it's just wrong.  You need it to flip all the bits of negative numbers (not just the bottom bit), and for the macros to be the reverse of each other (so `FLIP_FLOAT_B(FLIP_FLOAT_A(X)) == X` for all values of `X`).  Try:

```
#define FLIP_FLOAT_A(x) ((x)^(((~(x) >> 31)-1) | 0x80000000))
#define FLIP_FLOAT_B(x) ((x)^((((x) >> 31)-1) | 0x80000000))
```

Comment: FLIP_FLOAT_A converts -0 to 0x7FFFFFFF, and +0 to 0x80000000, so -0 would be less than +0, a potential stability issue. I don't know if the result of any float operation could produce a -0 float value, so it may not be an issue.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: It works! Thanks.
rcgldr: there's no negative zero, so it's not an issue.

Comment: @MiroslavCetojevic - this define for FLIP_FLOAT_A is a bit faster on my system: #define FLIP_FLOAT_A(x) ((x)^((0-((x) >> 31)  ) | 0x80000000)). It probably uses a negate instead of doing a 1's complement and a subtract of 1.

Comment: @rcgldr: which system? I'm running a VM on a Intel64 processor.

Comment: @MiroslavCetojevic - The change I'm suggestion for FLIP_FLOAT_A duplicates the inline function used in  Michael Herf's radix sort. I've also used this before in cases where I don't care that -0 is < +0 . I've tested on Win XP / Win 7, using Visual Studio 2005 to 2015. My suggested change reduces a one's complement followed by a subtract to just a subtract, or a negate (since it's a subtract from zero).